# What is the dimension of the subspace of $\mathcal C(X)$ constituted by $\{X\gamma: H'\gamma=0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any matrix $X$ let $\mathcal C(X)$ denote the column space of $X$.

> Consider the subspace of $\mathcal C(X)$, defined by $\{X\gamma: H'\gamma=0\}$, where $X,H$ are some matrices. What is the dimension of this space?

Solution given in my book:

> The condition $H'\gamma=0$ means $\gamma$ is orthogonal to $\mathcal C(H)$.So the question asks to look at the vector space of all vectors orthogonal to $\mathcal C(H)$, and obtain the subspace of $\mathcal C(X)$ by doing $X\gamma$.

And now the statement I do not understand.

> This precisely means that, if we agree to call the subspace $S=\{X\gamma:H'\gamma=0\}$ then $\dim(S)=rank[X' \space|\space H]-rank[H]$.

It would be really helpful if one explains this statement. Thanks!

Comment: Does it hold for $\mathbf X=0$? 0 = 0 - rank[H]?

Comment: @Ignat If $X$ is 0, then you have $0= \texttt{dim}(S) = \texttt{rank}(H) - \texttt{rank}(H) = 0$ as $\texttt{rank}[ 0 | H ] = \texttt{rank}(H).$

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri What is the meaning of $rank(X'|H)$? I supposed that it denotes the restriction of $\mathbf X'$ to $range(\mathbf H)$.

Comment: @Ignat It is the matrix constructed by concatenating the columns of $X^T$ and $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ denote the subspace $\{ \gamma : H^T\gamma = 0 \}$.

Applying the rank + nullity theorem to the restriction of $X$ to $V$, which we denote by $X_V$, leads to the result.

Since $V$ is the null space of $H^T$, the dimension of $V$ is $n - \texttt{rank}(H^T) = n - \texttt{rank}(H),$ where $n$ is the number of columns in $H^T$ (and also $X$).

The null space of $X_V$ is $$\{ \gamma : \gamma \in V \text{such that }X\gamma = 0\}$$ i.e., $$\{\gamma : X\gamma =0 ,H^T\gamma = 0\}$$ which is the same as $$ \{ \gamma : \begin{pmatrix} X \\ H^T \end{pmatrix} \gamma = 0 \}.$$
It is identical to the null space of $\begin{pmatrix} X \\ H^T \end{pmatrix}$ and by the rank + nullity theorem its dimension is $n - \texttt{rank}\begin{pmatrix} X \\ H^T \end{pmatrix} = n - \texttt{rank}[ X^T | H ]$  (where $n$ the number of columns in $X$).

The range of $X_V$ is precisely $S$ by definition of $S$.

The rank + nullity theorem applied to  $X_V$ gives : $$\texttt{dim}(\texttt{range}(X_V)) + \texttt{dim}(\texttt{kernel}(X_V)) = \texttt{dim}(V)$$ or $$\texttt{dim}(S) + n - \texttt{rank}[ X^T | H ] = n - \texttt{rank}(H)$$ which leads to $$\texttt{dim}(S) = \texttt{rank}[ X^T | H ] - \texttt{rank}(H)$$ as expected.